# Datediff function() giving me wrong answer

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using `SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,$StartDate, $Today)` to calculate the number of days between 2 dates. `$$StartDate` is 2020-11-19 and `$Today` is current date (`$Today = date("Y-m-d");`). I am getting 28 days as the number of days which is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need sql server for this? https://3v4l.org/GvA5c or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: thanks. 3v4l.org/GvA5c  worked

Answer (score 4):

To answer the actual question of why the value is "wrong" it's because it **isn't**; `28` *is* correct for the values you have passed. The problem is you *aren't* parametrising. `DATEDIFF` is actually working completely correctly. What you are doing is the following:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,2020-11-19, 2021-02-01);
```

That returns `28`. That is **correct**. What you have is a synonym of the following expressions as well:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,1990,2018);
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,'19050614','19070712');
--and even
SELECT 2018 - 1990;
```

Because you aren't properly parametrising (and injecting) the value you are passing isn't a datetime value, it's an expression of **`int`s**. Parametrise your query, and pass a date and time date type value, and the SQL works perfectly correctly. For example:

```sql
--This wouldn't be in your SQL, but something equivilent would happen when the parameters are pass from your application
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20201119',
        @Today date = '20210201';
--And the DATEDIFF function
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate, @Today);
```

This also returns the correct value for the expression, but also the value you likely expect, `74`.